# How to get the specific sub-string position in a string

Tags: c#, string, substring

I have a string `121712  1512  0025            64559         7259181568        701  013              2`.Now as per my requirement i have to get the last sub-string `2`  `StartIndex` and `EndIndex` .But here the issue is with the point that `2` is coming in the first substring `121712` so it is taking from there which i dont want ..
Here is the code that i have tried..

```
        string s = "121712  1512  0025            64559         7259181568        701  013              2 ";

        string inout = "2";

        string[] arrs = s.Split(' ');

        for (int i = 0; i <= arrs.Length; i++)
        {
            string str = arrs[i];
            if (str == inout)
            {

                int startIndex = s.IndexOf(arrs[i]);

                int endIndex = s.IndexOf(" ", startIndex);

                int difference = endIndex - startIndex;

                string inoutSubstring = (startIndex + "," + difference);
            }
        }
```

Please help me to resolve the issue ..Thanks.

Comment: Looks like this is not C

Comment: @ThisaruGuruge Sorry my mistake it happened for c, Actually its c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said last substring Right??

s.LastIndexOf(inout) will give the starting index of Inout string. Now I need to get endindex of Inout in s string. add inout.Lenght-1 into s.LastIndexOf(inout) that will give Last index of inout string.

You can do for any string just assign new sting int inout variable like of "21" , "12" or many other.

```
        string inout = "2";
        int startIndex;
        int endIndex;
        startIndex = s.LastIndexOf(inout);
        endIndex = startIndex + inout.Length-1;
```

Comment: Thnk you sir for understanding my question .I would like to point one more thing that suppose inout varible value is at middle or at some other place in the string except at last place supposing which you have given solution in this case how will this solution work ?

Comment: Ya its ok....it will work...Your aim is u just want to get last substring.....if same substring present in start or middle u don't need that u need only last substring....

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to find the last incidence of a substring within a string. The `String` object in C# has a method designed for exactly this, `String.LastIndexOf`:

```
string s = "121712  1512  0025            64559         7259181568        701  013              2 ";

string inout = "2";

string[] arrs = s.Split(' ');

for (int i = 0; i <= arrs.Length; i++)
{
     string str = arrs[i];
     if (str == inout)
     {
         int startIndex = s.IndexOf("2");
         int endIndex = s.LastIndexOf("2");
     }
 }
```

Note that both of these methods will return -1 if they can't find an incidence of the substring. Additionally, if there's only a single incidence of a substring, they'll both return the same value.

Comment: OK.Let me make it more clear.Suppose the substring is `21` instead of `2` and it can be anywhere in the Whole string as separate substring .IN this case my aim will be to get startindex and endindex so that i can get this substring out by giving this numbers

Comment: @HansalMehta That's fine - just substitute `21` where `2` is. Both methods accept a plain old string.

Comment: Actually my concern is that `2` is present in `121712` also . And if i try to find the indexof of `2` it will always get it from first occurrence i.e from `121712` whereas we want it from last place or just anyother place where only `2` is present and same is application in example case of `23`

Comment: Are you there Sir ...?

Comment: @HansalMehta Yeah, as I explained in the post, that's the entire point of `LastIndexOf`. For `121712`, `IndexOf("2")` will return `1`, whereas `LastIndexOf("2")` will return `5`.